# How to debug self signed certificate?

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, windows-10

I have created a self signed certificate and imported the CA cert into Trusted Root Certification Authorities but Chrome still gives me `ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID`. I have followed https://gist.github.com/jchandra74/36d5f8d0e11960dd8f80260801109ab0 this guide. When opening the domain in Chrome the PEM encoded chain gives me the server and the certificate I supplied. I set both `commonName` and `DNS.1` under `alt_names` to `my.site.com` and started `chrome --host-rules="MAP my.site.com 127.0.0.1"`. How could I debug this? How can I check whether Chrome sees the CA I imported, and whether it tries to use it with this cert Apache supplies?

If I bypass the warning, under security in Developer Tools I see "Certificate - valid and trusted. The connection to this site is using a valid, trusted server certificate issued by unknown name." but "Certificate - missing This site is missing a valid, trusted certificate (net::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID)."

What I would like to see is something like "In field X of the certificate, expected Y, got Z".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once `chrome --host-rules="MAP my.site.com 127.0.0.1"` is supplied Chrome does not look for a certificate for `my.site.com` instead it wants `127.0.0.1`.

Make sure you have `IP.1 = 127.0.0.1` in your `alt_names` section.